# Incorrect virtual function called in templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

My problem is that when I call a virtual function on an object passed to my callback function, the wrong function gets called, and I get a run-time error.

Consider the following code fragment in a header file. The code may not compile as it is only a fragment.

```
class CEventBase1{
protected:
    virtual void Show(int code){}
private:
    static void _Base1Callback(void*ptr){
        CEventBase1* pThis = static_cast<CEventBase1*>(ptr);
        pThis->Show(EVENT_CODE);
    }
};

class CEventBase2{
protected:
    virtual void Move(int code){}
private:
    static void _Base2Callback(void*ptr){
        CEventBase2* pThis = static_cast<CEventBase2*>(ptr);
        pThis-> Move(EVENT_MOVE);
    }
};

class CAllEvents: public CEventBase1, public CEventBase2{
};

template<typename EVENTS>
class CWindow : public EVENTS{
};

class CMyEvents: public CAllEvents{
public:
    virtual void Move(int code){
        // Some processing
    }
};

CWindow<CMyEvents> myWin;
```

This code will interact with some library in which the window instance is registered to handle events. Something similar to:

```
int main () {
    SomeLibraryRegisterCallbackData(&myWin);
    SomeLibraryRegisterEvent1Callback(CEventBase1::_Base1Callback);
    SomeLibraryRegisterEvent2Callback(CEventBase2::_Base2Callback);
    return SomeLibraryDispatch();
}
```

The idea is that during the dispatch, the pointer to `myWin` gets passed to a registered callback whenever the event it is registered against occurs.

**Problem**: When the program tries to call the `CMyEvents::Move()` from the static function `_Base2Callback()`, the `CEventBase1::Show()` function gets called and the program crashes in the caller function as soon as `Show()` returns with the error:

> **`ESP pointer is of incorrect type. this may happen when an incorrect method is called`**

**Compiler**: Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: The code does not compile. Please make it self-contained.

Comment: this is an extract not the actual code. I placed the code here so that anyone can understand the problem.

Comment: Take the actual code, shorten it to the bare minimum, such that it compiles and still exhibits the problem. In other words, create a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please don't call other people *idiot*, even if you're angry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing in a pointer to a `CWindow<CMyEvents>` instance to `CEventBase2::_Base2Callback`, then the static cast of the `void *` argument to `CEventBase2 *` is in error. Although there is an ***is-a*** relationship between the two, it is through multiple inheritance. In practical terms, this means that the object layout is such that for an instance of `CMyEvents`, its address is not the same as the address of the `CEventBase2` instance from which it is derived.

The straightforward way to avoid this problem is to avoid using `void *` altogether. However, since you are using a library, then you must make your code compatible with the framework. In your case, you want each base class to define its own callback function. This means that the base class needs to be aware of the derived type, because it is the pointer to the derived type that is being passed into the callback function.

This can be accomplished using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Make each base class a template class that is parameterized by its derived class. Then, the callback function can cast to the derived type:

```
template <typename DERIVED>
class CEventBase1{
protected:
    virtual void Show(int code){}
protected:
    static void _Base1Callback(void*ptr){
        DERIVED* pThis = static_cast<DERIVED*>(ptr);
        pThis->Show(EVENT_CODE);
    }
};

template <typename DERIVED>
class CEventBase2{
protected:
    virtual void Move(int code){}
private:
    static void _Base2Callback(void*ptr){
        DERIVED* pThis = static_cast<DERIVED*>(ptr);
        pThis-> Move(EVENT_MOVE);
    }
};
```

You would also make `CAllEvents` a template class as well, so it can properly pass the right derived type to the base classes:

```
template <typename DERIVED>
class CAllEvents: public CEventBase1<DERIVED>, public CEventBase2<DERIVED>{
};
```

And now, the user of the of that class uses it like this:

```
class CMyEvents: public CAllEvents<CMyEvents>{
public:
    void Move(int code){
        // Some processing
    }
};
```

Because of the way `CWindow<>` is defined, the address of an instance of it would be the same as the address of the `CMyEvents` instance from which it is derived. The callback functions in the base classes will cast the pointer to a `CMyEvents*`.

Comment: @Oswald: The bug is that the static cast is wrong. Although cast to `CEventBase2`, the address is wrong, so the wrong v-table is used, and the wrong virtual function gets called as a result.

Comment: Yes, I realized this as soon as I made the comment and deleted it right away (but apparently not fast enough).

Comment: @SimpleFellow: I think you understand the cause of your problem, but I don't think I understand why you can't resolve it. Can you add a little more code to your question that shows how you are registering the callbacks?

Comment: can we chat? in the stack overflow room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39026/c-pointer-template-problems